# How to change a field based on user's selection in an HTML select?

Tags: javascript, coldfusion, coldfusion-8

I have a select list containing variables from a query

```
<tr>
  <td>County Name:</td>
    <td>
      <select name="countyName" onchange="countyID.value = countyName.value">
                <option>Select a County</option>
        <cfloop query = "getCounties">
        <option value="#countyName#" >#countyName#&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;#countyID#</option>
        </cfloop>
    </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

How can I populate the County ID field?

```
<tr>
  <td>County ID:</td>
    <td><input type="Text" name="countyID">
     </td>
</tr>
```

I've never used jQuery. Is there a way to use just JavaScript? As you can see I've attempted JavaScript, however I can only populate `countyID` with the `countyName` and I need it populated with `countyID`.

Comment: Please indent your code by 4 spaces (e.g., by selecting it and pressing the code `{}` button); don't use backticks the way you did. BTW, how do you set `countyID` and `countyName`?

Comment: Thank you - as you can see - I'm also fairly new to posting in StackOverflow!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Breaking it out into a function this should work for you: **[Live Example](http://www.jsfiddle.net/subhaze/vQLqm/)**

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr> <td>County ID:</td> <td><input id="countyId" type="Text" name="countyID"> </td> </tr>
        <tr> <td>County Name:</td> 

            <td> 
                <select name="countyName" onchange="update(this)">
                    <option>Select a County</option> 
                    <option value="1234">asdf</option> 
                    <option value="4321">asdf2</option> 
                </select> 
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script>
    function update( elem ) {
    document.getElementById('countyID').value = elem.value;
    }
</script>
```

---

Or in short just change

this:

```
<select name="countyName" onchange="countyID.value = countyName.value">
```

to this, and it should work

```
<select name="countyName" onchange="document.getElementById('countyId').value = this.value">
```

You need to reference your DOM elements via `document.getElementById()` and not just their id alone

**[Another example here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/subhaze/vQLqm/2/)**

Comment: The OP is essentially doing exactly this, but he needs to use the `countyId` for the option value, as opposed to the `countyName`

Comment: as well as accessing it via `document.getElementById()`

Comment: Thank you both subhaze and Dutchie432 - it works! 
I additionally have a field CountyCode which is the same as CountyID (both countyID and countyCode) need to be inserted into the database table.

Comment: Tried adding another onchange coding to the countyID field however, that didn't work.
Sorry, this darn table design is not normalized. I actually have a couple other sets of fields that contain duplicate data needing to be inserted into each field. I've not been able to get those to work using this (similar) code. If I was to use the script mentioned would I need a separate script for each element id?

Comment: @skeddy Was looking through my account here and just saw your comment. This might not be of value anymore :P or the best approach but you could set each `select` elements class name to the id of the element you wish to change. Doing it this way however means you can Not add any other classes to the select element. Here is an example: http://www.jsfiddle.net/subhaze/vQLqm/3/

Answer (score 5):

Just out of curiousity, why are you using `#countyName#` as the values for your options? What if the county (erroneously or not) has a quotaton mark or something else that will screw with your HTML.

Why wouldn't you do:

```
<select name="countyName" onchange="countyID.value = this.value">
    <option value="#countyID#">#countyName#</option>
</select>
```